# Using FormMixin with DetailView?

Tags: python, django

In detail page:
We want to display form:According docs,We must be used wrapper:

> from django.views import View

```
class CommentGet(DetailView): 
    model = Article
    template_name = "article_detail.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = CommentForm()
        return context

class CommentPost(SingleObjectMixin, FormView): 
    model = Article
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "article_detail.html"
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.article = self.object
        comment.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
         article = self.get_object()
         return reverse("article_detail", kwargs={"pk": article.pk})
class CView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = CommentGet.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = CommentPost.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Are we could simply used post method with detailview?

```
class Detail(DetailView):
    model = ... 
    def post(self):
        #do something here.
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, but I've often added `SingleObjectMixin` to `FormView` which results in something pretty similar, but with a `post` method for processing the form.

The one thing you have to know with this, is that it's your responsibility to invoke  `self.object = self.get_object()` or otherwise retrieve the object to display. You can do this in `get_context_data` and in `form_valid` (the latter if it's needed to deal with the valid form, which it usually is).

[Classy class-based views](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) is an invaluable resource for working out subclassing and mixins with CBVs